Use results from one query in WHERE clause of the next query
This is how it currently works, first select query returns a list of parameters.
SELECT character_id, foe_id, location_id, date_time, damage, points 
FROM events 
ORDER BY date_time DESC 
LIMIT 100

Now, the following is iterated 100 times to complete the data, for example the first one returns:
  character_id = 12695
, location_id = 818
, foe_id = 33997
, date_time = '2024-05-02 23:00:00'

The following query is based on these results:
SELECT *, A1+B1-C1-D1-E1-F1+G1+H1 AS A2 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM 
         (SELECT id_, cnt_7, date_diff_7 , NTH_VALUE (A0,1) OVER() AS A1, NTH_VALUE (A0,2) OVER() AS B1, NTH_VALUE (B0,1) OVER() AS C1, NTH_VALUE (B0,2) OVER() AS D1 
          FROM 
              (SELECT damage AS A0, points AS B0, RootQuery_7.id as id_, count(*) over() as cnt_7,  max(date_diff) over() as date_diff_7 
               FROM 
                   (SELECT *, extract(day from date_time - lag(date_time) over (ORDER BY date_time)) as date_diff 
                    FROM events 
                    WHERE character_id = 12695 
                      AND status = 1 
                      AND location_id = 818 
                      AND date_time < '2024-05-02 23:00:00' 
                    ORDER BY date_time DESC 
                    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) AS RootQuery_7) 
            AS BaseQuery7 LIMIT 1) wnd_1 
        JOIN (SELECT id_, cnt_8, date_diff_8 , NTH_VALUE (D0,2) OVER() AS H1, NTH_VALUE (C0,1) OVER() AS E1, NTH_VALUE (C0,2) OVER() AS F1, NTH_VALUE (D0,1) OVER() AS G1 FROM 
            (SELECT damage AS C0, points AS D0, RootQuery_8.id as id_, count(*) over() as cnt_8,  max(date_diff) over() as date_diff_8 FROM 
                (SELECT *, extract(day from date_time - lag(date_time) over (ORDER BY date_time)) as date_diff FROM events WHERE foe_id = 33997 AND status = 1 AND location_id = 818 AND date_time < '2024-05-02 23:00:00' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0)
                    AS RootQuery_8)
            AS BaseQuery8 LIMIT 1) wnd_2
    ON wnd_1.id_ <> 0 WHERE cnt_7 >= 10 AND date_diff_7 <= 150 AND cnt_8 >= 10 AND date_diff_8 <= 150) AS layer_1

It works but is too inefficient and slow, please don't mind the verisimilitude of the data retrieved, since it is an example.
I am trying to get this list of results from a single query like this:
(SELECT character_id, foe_id, location_id, date_time, damage, points FROM events ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 100) ref_
JOIN
SELECT *, A1+B1-C1-D1-E1-F1+G1+H1 AS A2 FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT id_, cnt_7, date_diff_7 , NTH_VALUE (A0,1) OVER() AS A1, NTH_VALUE (A0,2) OVER() AS B1, NTH_VALUE (B0,1) OVER() AS C1, NTH_VALUE (B0,2) OVER() AS D1 FROM 
            (SELECT damage AS A0, points AS B0, RootQuery_7.id as id_, count(*) over() as cnt_7,  max(date_diff) over() as date_diff_7 FROM 
                (SELECT *, extract(day from date_time - lag(date_time) over (ORDER BY date_time)) as date_diff FROM events WHERE character_id = ref_.character_id  AND status = 1 AND location_id = ref_.location_id AND date_time < location_id = ref_.date_time ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0)te_time
                    AS RootQuery_7) 
            AS BaseQuery7 LIMIT 1) wnd_1 
        JOIN (SELECT id_, cnt_8, date_diff_8 , NTH_VALUE (D0,2) OVER() AS H1, NTH_VALUE (C0,1) OVER() AS E1, NTH_VALUE (C0,2) OVER() AS F1, NTH_VALUE (D0,1) OVER() AS G1 FROM 
            (SELECT damage AS C0, points AS D0, RootQuery_8.id as id_, count(*) over() as cnt_8,  max(date_diff) over() as date_diff_8 FROM 
                (SELECT *, extract(day from date_time - lag(date_time) over (ORDER BY date_time)) as date_diff FROM events WHERE foe_id = ref_.foe_id  AND status = 1 AND location_id = ref_.location_id AND date_time < location_id = ref_.date_time ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0)
                    AS RootQuery_8)
            AS BaseQuery8 LIMIT 1) wnd_2
    ON wnd_1.id_ <> 0 WHERE cnt_7 >= 10 AND date_diff_7 <= 150 AND cnt_8 >= 10 AND date_diff_8 <= 150) AS layer_1
ON ...

But the result of the first query results cannot be used within the deepest layer of selects in the second query.

.make some CTE só you can acces the results of the queries

When a query is slow, start getting the query plan using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings). Then you can see why it is slow and what to improve.

@FrankHeikens no, no the query is not the problem, the problem is that i have to run it 100 times to retrieve the data i need

@nbk im not trying to run a query from the result of an another query, but to use the results of the first query as a parameter for the WHERE clause in the seccond one, thanks for the reply btw!

TLDR: Use a LATERAL join.
LATERAL joins allow subqueries to the right to reference columns in FROM items to the left. See:

What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?

Your query could look something like this:
SELECT *, A1+B1-C1-D1-E1-F1+G1+H1 AS A2
FROM  (
   SELECT character_id, foe_id, location_id, date_time, damage, points FROM events ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 100
   ) prime
JOIN LATERAL (  -- !
   SELECT id_, cnt_7, date_diff_7
        , nth_value(A0,1) OVER () AS A1, nth_value(A0,2) OVER () AS B1, nth_value(B0,1) OVER () AS C1, nth_value(B0,2) OVER () AS D1
   FROM  (
      SELECT damage AS A0, points AS B0, RootQuery_7.id AS id_, count(*) OVER () AS cnt_7,  max(date_diff) OVER () AS date_diff_7
      FROM  (
         SELECT *, extract(day FROM e.date_time - lag(e.date_time) OVER (ORDER BY e.date_time)) AS date_diff
         FROM   events e
         WHERE  e.status = 1
         AND    e.character_id = prime.character_id  -- LATERAL reference
         AND    e.location_id  = prime.location_id   -- LATERAL reference
         AND    e.date_time    < prime.date_time     -- LATERAL reference
         ORDER  BY e.date_time DESC
         LIMIT  10
         ) AS RootQuery_7
      ) AS BaseQuery7
      LIMIT 1
   ) wnd_1 ON wnd_1.id_ <> 0
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (  -- !
   SELECT id_, cnt_8, date_diff_8 , nth_value(D0,2) OVER () AS H1, nth_value(C0,1) OVER () AS E1, nth_value(C0,2) OVER () AS F1, nth_value(D0,1) OVER () AS G1
   FROM  (
      SELECT damage AS C0, points AS D0, RootQuery_8.id AS id_, count(*) OVER () AS cnt_8,  max(date_diff) OVER () AS date_diff_8
      FROM  (
         SELECT *, extract(day from date_time - lag(date_time) OVER (ORDER BY date_time)) AS date_diff
         FROM   events
         WHERE  status = 1
         AND    foe_id      = prime.foe_id       -- LATERAL reference
         AND    location_id = prime.location_id  -- LATERAL reference
         AND    date_time   < prime.date_time    -- LATERAL reference
         ORDER  BY date_time DESC
         LIMIT  15
         ) RootQuery_8
      ) BaseQuery8
   LIMIT 1
   ) wnd_2
WHERE  wnd_1.cnt_7 >= 10
AND    wnd_1.date_diff_7 <= 150
AND    wnd_2.cnt_8 >= 10
AND    wnd_2.date_diff_8 <= 150;

Can certainly be simplified further. But that's beyond the scope of this question.
Two instances of LIMIT 1 without ORDER BY lead to arbitrary results. Should probably be fixed (or removed).
Aside:
Avoid mixed-case identifiers in Postgres if at all possible. See:

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?


Thanks a lot, youre answer is pure gold, just what i needed! the reason for that "LIMIT 1" in the windows query is because it returns 10 rows with the exact same output
